# Sorting table of results

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Sorting a winner.

How would you get the winner of a competition PHP/MYSQL.

Total value is the factor that decides the winner. 
But on a draw the one with the highest value wins. 
Compare best result first if still draw compare the second value ..

DB table has playerid, result fields.

```
Playerid result
1        100
1         80
1         80
2        100
2         80
2         40
2         40
3        160
3        100
4        130
4        130
5        270
```

List of results

```
Player1  100,80,80 
Player2  100,80,40,40
Player3  160,100
Player4  130,130
Player5  270
```

WANTED RESULT

```
Player5 
Player3
Player4
Player1
Player2
```

Comment: Just sort on result for each player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply select with `group by` and `ORDER BY SUM(result) DESC, COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT PlayerId, SUM(result) res FROM resulttbl GROUP BY PlayerId 
ORDER BY res DESC,COUNT(*)
```

I added the second sorting criterion as I am guessing that you want those players with fewer entries (=fewer games?) listed first.

Or you can do

```
select PlayerId from resulttbl GROUP BY PlayerId 
ORDER BY sum(result) DESC, COUNT(*)
```

if you don't want the sum of the results listed.

You can find a working demo here: http://rextester.com/GTHMG11363

Comment: If I have the results in column comma seprated would still be possible to sort everything. playerid and column result would have a comma separated string of all values? http://rextester.com/JORQ75158

Comment: I suppose there is a way to do it. It would involve splitting the string, counting its parts and applying some math on it, but it is definitely not the way you work with a relational database. The original approach is to be preferred.

Comment: http://rextester.com/GTHMG11363 I ran some tests with real data and it is not sorting right as the best result should always be on top if it is a draw. There are 5 results at 233 but team 551 should be on top with result 71.

Comment: select teamid, sum(result) res, group_concat(result order by result DESC) rlist from resulttable GROUP BY teamid ORDER BY sum(result) desc, rlist DESC